# Connecting to a server with the ehternet shield in Arduino

Tags: server, arduino, ethernet

I'm developing a simple code that allows me to connecting to a server in my LAN. But it doesn't work, it doesn't connect.
I'm trying to make it work in every way but it doesn't work either way.

Here is my code:

```cpp
#include <SPI.h>
#include <Ethernet.h>
byte mac[] = { 0x90, 0xA2, 0xDA, 0x11, 0x03, 0xE9 };
char server[] = "http://172.17.17.55";    

IPAddress ip(172, 17, 17, 60);
EthernetClient client;

void setup() { 

  Serial.begin(9600);
  while (!Serial) {
    ; 
  }

  Ethernet.begin(mac, ip);

  delay(1000);
  Serial.println("connecting...");

  if (client.connect(server, 8008)) {
    Serial.println("connected");

    client.println("GET /172.17.17.55/ HTTP/1.1");

    client.println();
  } else {
    Serial.println("connection failed");
  }
}

void loop() {

  if (client.available()) {
    char c = client.read();
    Serial.print(c);
  }

  if (!client.connected()) {
    Serial.println();
    Serial.println("disconnecting.");
    client.stop();

    while (true);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the `http://` from your server address:

```
char server[] = "172.17.17.55";
```

or better still, since you know the IP address anyway, you can just use:

```
IPAddress server(172, 17, 17, 55);
```

which will avoid a DNS lookup.